# laço for in retomando o índice "length" de um nodlist, isso é normal? alguma dica pra resolver isso?

Tags: javascript

como disse o laço for in pecorre todos os indices e retorna os indices, nesse caso sao (0,1,2), ele tambem esta retornando o indice length do nodelist que eu to pecorrendo, assim ao usar o indice retornado pra acessar outro array, o codigo tenta recuperar o valor do indice length(3), ocasionado um erro ja que este indice (3) nao esta definido`

```
for(let iBox in boxSlider){
        let boxMain = boxSlider[iBox];
        for(let iCol of colecao[(iBox)]){
        boxMain.innerHTML += `
        <a href="" class="pr">
            <img src="${iCol.imagem}" alt="">
            <span class="tittle">${iCol.nome}</span>
        </a>`;
        }
    }
```

Obs: boxSlider é o nodlist

Answer (score 0):

Os atributos do nodeList são tratados como índices pelo loop.

Transforme o `NodeList` num `Array` de fato através da função `Array.from`:

```
for(let iBox in Array.from(boxSlider)){
  let boxMain = boxSlider[iBox];
  for(let iCol of colecao[(iBox)]){
  boxMain.innerHTML += `
  <a href="" class="pr">
      <img src="${iCol.imagem}" alt="">
      <span class="tittle">${iCol.nome}</span>
  </a>`;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use um `for` simples que você tem controle do índice

```
for (let iBox = 0; i < boxSlider.length; iBox++) {
    let boxMain = boxSlider[iBox];
    // ...
}
```

Comment: sim, foi o que fiz